# Can I trust objectForKey right after setObject in NSCache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscache

Considering this sample code (cache is an instance of NSCache):

```
- (id)objFromCache
{
    if ([cache objectForKey:@"myObject"] == nil)
        [cache setObject:[self generateObject] forKey:@"myObject"];

    return [cache objectForKey:@"myObject"];
}
```

Should I trust this code? I mean, will `objectForKey:@"myObject"` ever return nil right after `setObject:forKey:@"myObject"`? If so, whould I change `if` to `while`?

What's the best way to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I wasn't notified there were answers. I've accepted it. That's exactly how I've been using since my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in a multi-threaded environment you cannot assume that `NSCache` returns the object
that you just inserted.

Also if the first call `[cache objectForKey:@"myObject"]` does not return `nil`, the second one in the return statement could return `nil`.

So I would play it safe and write your method as

```
- (id)objFromCache
{
    id value = [cache objectForKey:@"myObject"];
    if (value == nil) {
        value = [self generateObject];
        [cache setObject:value forKey:@"myObject"];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: In a multithreaded environment, that still wouldn't be safe because you may end up creating two objects... A lock would be the right way in that case.

Comment: @JustSid: I don't think so. From the `NSCache` documentation: *"You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different threads without having to lock the cache yourself."* - `NSCache` is different from `NSMutableDictionary` in that aspect.

Comment: @MartinR There is a race condition in your code, not in `NSCache` ;)

Comment: @JustSid: OK, I think I see now what you mean. I had assumed that `generateObject` always returns the same object, because it is used to re-create a cached item. But if that method is not thread-safe then a lock could be necessary.

Comment: @MartinR Wouldn't that make the `objFromCache` method useless?

Comment: @JustSid: I am expressing myself badly, sorry. I used NSCache once to cache the result from `[UINib nibWithNibName:...]` because I had read that that is an expensive operation. In that case, it does not matter if `[UINib nibWithNibName:...]` is called twice from different threads, because the return values are representing the same nib file, so it does not matter which one is put into the cache.

Comment: @MartinR Good point, but you are potentially doing an expensive operations multiple times. Oh well, I guess it's just Haarspalterei at this point.